# Javascript Array ES6 Undefined Error

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble solving this question (the result is always undefined) and I am not sure what I'm doing wrong... any ideas?

Write a function that takes a number and generates a list from 0 to that number.

Use the function to assign a value to the `myNumberList` variable so that it has the value of a list going from 0 to 5.

Assign a value to the variable `secondLastItem` that should be the second last item of the `myNumberList` array.

```
function listMaker(listLength) {}

var myNumberList = null; // replace with number list created by listmaker

var secondLastItem = null; // replace with second last item
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @4castle I get undefined if I do it like so:                                            
function listMaker(listLength) {
  Array.apply(null, {length: listLength}).map(Number.call, Number)
}

listMaker(10);

Comment: You're missing a `return` statement in your code. Otherwise, it looks fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following way using `ES6`'s spread operator (`...`):

```js
function listMaker(listLength) { 
   return [...Array(listLength).keys()];
} 
var myNumberList = listMaker(10);
// If you want the specified number passed as argument to be included as the last item in the array then push it.
myNumberList.push(10);
console.log(myNumberList);
```

Comment: How would we make the list also list N? So, it would list 10 here too?

Comment: @user8227859, I am not clear about requirement. Can you tell me little bit in detail, like what is the output you are expecting for which output.

Comment: @user8227859, may be you want the `10` to be included in the list as well. The argument you are passing is the length of the array to be created. Since the array index starts from 0, you are getting array up to 9. If you want the specified number to be included as the last item in the array either you have to pass the number+1 or add 1 in the return statement. Please check the answer. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to write it:

```js
     function listMaker(number) {
       var secondToLast;
       var list = [];
       
        for (var i = 0; i <= number; i++){
        list.push(i);
         }
         secondToLast = list[list.length - 2];
          
         return [list, secondToLast]
        }
        
        
        var list = listMaker(5)[0];
        var secondToLast = listMaker(5)[1] 

console.log(list + "\n" + secondToLast);
```

That is the snippet ^

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qeqm8fph/2/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to run on repl.it?

Comment: I had a jsfiddle with it working. Hmmm. Im on a phone now so ill have to check it out later